# Delete uploaded image if user goes from the page

Tags: c#, jquery, html, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I develop web application functionality sending message with attached image to another user. User can see preview of the image and make some crop before sending. 
So at first I upload the image to the server and than show this image for user for preview. But what if user just close browser or go to another page, then there will be unused image file on the server. How to handle it? Or maybe there is better approach that don't need to upload image to the server at all?

Comment: Can you use windows services ?

Comment: Why do you need to upload for user to crop in browser? Only upload if they are going to send

Comment: I don't know how to make a crop of image that isn't loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that can be done using [JavaScript's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) [`FileReader`](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader). You can edit the image on the client side without having to upload the image to the server. Then you can perform the upload only when the user opts to send the message. This article has an example of such functionality: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Crop-and-Upload-Image-with-Thumbnail-using-jQuery-and-HTML5-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To provide a good user experience a website should give him a welcome back. So in your case you can use the [AnonymousIdentification](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx) to keep track of your returned users even if the browser is crashed or the tab is closed.

You can keep the information related to that specific anonymous user and keep track of them with their activities including the Image uploading (in your case). Then if the doesn't come back for a specific time of period you can delete that uploaded image.

> Or maybe there is better approach that don't need to upload image to the server at all?

Yes it can be achieved via HTML5 features for file handling and canvas feature.

See these links for details:
[Html5_ImageUploader](https://github.com/rossturner/HTML5-ImageUploader)
[Drag&Drop with Crop via Ajax](http://html5.sapnagroup.com/2012/08/preview-and-crop-before-upload/)

Answer (score 0):

I have built this before with a timestamp, after the crop you remove the timestamp in the table.

Have a service that runs say every 15 minute and looks for unconfirmed images and then delete from the server. This obviously still gives the data transfer but works quite well. I don't know how to handle EACH client close (even browser crashes....)

Answer (score 0):

this plugins http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/
http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html  will crop image without upload to server.